# Use of the word 'respectively'

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I want to know if the following sentence is grammatically correct:
"John's largest tomato and largest pumpkin outweighed Bill's by 2 and 17 pounds, respectively."

I am trying to say "John's largest tomato outweighs Bill's largest tomato by 2 pounds and his largest pumpkin outweighs Bill's by 17 pounds."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. It means "separately or individually and in the order already mentioned (used when enumerating two or more items or facts that refer back to a previous statement). [[OxfordDictionaries via Google](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/respectively)]

Comment: That usage of _respectively_ is definitely correct, though I wonder if the comma before respectively is always necessary. I would have dropped that comma. Can anyone comment on that?

Comment: It is best to check for duplicates before answering.